# what exactly do i need to make jsonp request in backbone?

Tags: backbone.js

according to this article http://iainjmitchell.com/blog/?p=777, i am suppose to override sync. But without overriding sync, I am able to make JSONP request with the following:

```
var Tweet = Backbone.Model.extend();

var Tweets = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: Tweet,
url: 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%40twitterapi&callback=?',
parse: function(response) {
return response.results;
}
});

var tweets = new Tweets();

tweets.bind('reset', function(tweets) {
alert(tweets.length);
});

tweets.fetch();
```

So the question is, what is going on? I need overriding sync or not?

Answer (score -1):

Considering the default Backbone.sync uses `jQuery.ajax` you can go for:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    dataType: "jsonp"
});
```

JSONP will prevent you from using the entire Backbone REST api so i suggest you look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP and see if you really need JSONP.

More details here: [JSONP and Backbone.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169270/jsonp-and-backbone-js)